# Is there validate-able way to use HTML label and input elements and the input not having an id?

Tags: html, validation, input, label

I'm using `Jquery Mobile` for an application, which has a login popup on every page. The problem is, Jquery Mobile will always have at least 2 pages in the DOM, so I will have two popups and login forms in the DOm, forcing me to find a way to avoid `duplicate id-attributes`.

I worked around this by omitting the `id` attributes on the login form inputs, so I'm doing this:

```
 <label for="email" class="inFieldLabel">#tx_email#</label>
 <input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email" value="#XMLFormat( lostPass.email )#" class="required">
```

Which works fine visually, but produces a validation error, because:

```
 The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.
```

**Question**:
Is there a way to pass validation without using an `id` attribute? What would be workarounds?

Note: I can't use a global login popup, because this is not supported by Jquery Mobile at the moment, so I'm stuck with a popup on every page.

Thanks for insights!

Comment: Not the answer, though you don't have to use labels with ids. You can also simply wrap the tgt of the label with it to get the same effect. I.e <label><input type='radio'>Some text that acts like an rb</input></label>. But the 64,000 question seems to be why not use ids?

Comment: Good point though. Let me see if this works in JQM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the form control the label applies to inside the label.

```
<label> text <input> </label>
```

Comment: yup. that's how I ended up doing it. I had to rewrite some Jquery Mobile custom CSS but this is the way I'm going now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2 things: that you aren't going to be using IDs to style your form and you have a FORM tag around each  popup. This code will append a random number to the IDs/FORs of the elements of your form. You'll likely need to pass this number to your validate routine as well.

```
jQuery("FORM").each(function()
{
  var randomNum = Math.random()*1000;
  var jForm = jQuery(this);
  jForm.find("INPUT").each(function()
  {
    this.id+=randomNum;        
  });
  jForm.find("LABEL").each(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).attr("for",jQuery(this).attr("for")+randomNum);
  });
});

...

validateForm(form, randomNum);
```

That's one way to keep the IDs on your forms unique.

I guess I'm assuming you're using the Validate plugin as well. If it's any help, you *can* use multiple non-unique IDs for your forms/elements as long as you pass Validate unique selectors like "#page-1 #popup-form #myInput" or "#page-2 #popup-form #myInput".

**More edits:**

Wait, are you looking for this? You can reference a form and it's controls via name instead of id using the forms object.

```
<form name="formNameAttribute">
  <input name="inputNameAttribute" value="some value" />
</form>

<script>
var inputValue=document.forms["formNameAttribute"]["inputNameAttribute"].value;
</script>
```

Comment: hm. That would be an option, but sure adds complexity :-) I'm trying to see whether I can do the "wrap thing" as per the comments first :-)

Comment: Actually, the wrap thing is a good solution if that's all you need it for.

Comment: yeah, but totally breaks my css... still trying to update. if you want to make it an answer, please check

Comment: give me a little bit to post. My input & label were nicely positioned inside a list item. Say 35%/65%. If I now wrap the input inside the 35% label, this look... not good :-)